# How do i export HIGHCHARTS chart to a .jpeg

Tags: highcharts

I want to export a highchart to a jpeg image and place it into a specific folder.

What is the flow that goes through the **highscript.js**?

Answer (score 1):

You can export into jpeg ,but it renders on browser as api did not provide location .

API URL :http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#exporting

and

> $('#container').highcharts({
>
> ```
>     credits: {
>         enabled: false
>     },
>
>     xAxis: {
>         categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
>     },
>
>     series: [{
>         data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
>     }],
>
>     navigation: {
>         buttonOptions: {
>             enabled: false
>         }
>     },
>     exporting: {
>         type: 'image/jpeg'
>
>     }
>
> });
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can prepare your own server (http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/52-serverside-generated-charts) and define directory, where exported file should be saved, but you have no ability to have influence on customer / client direction (security aspects).